# Two variable hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are observed simultaneously. There is only one real datapoint $(X, Y)$ observed. Null hypothesis $H_0$ is that the variables are distributed according to some distribution $\rho(X, Y)$. The probability distribution does not have an analytic form, and thus is sampled numerically. It is known from simulations that $\rho$ is uni-modal and localized in space, and looks a bit like a rotated gaussian. I may get as many samples as I like from $\rho$. I would like to attempt to reject $H_0$. What are my options?

My naive approach to the problem would be as follows.

1. Get many samples from $\rho$
2. Estimate mean and covariance matrix of $\rho$
3. Apply a transformation in 2D space, such that after the transformation the data sampled from $\rho$ would have zero mean and unit covariance
4. Use distance from the origin in the transformed space as a test statistic.
5. Test whether the distance of the true datapoint exceeds 1% quantile (or whatever p-value I aim for) of distances sampled under the null hypothesis.

This sounds reasonable to me, but I am not sure it is robust.

**Edit**: I was asked about the origins of the problem, so here it is. I have a dataset, which is a set of random variables sampled experimentally. I am interested in studying a metric of this dataset, which outputs two numbers $X$ and $Y$. These two numbers are a function of the dataset, and are thus random variables themselves. I noticed that the metric is biased -  the variable $X$ should be approximately zero for a certain type of model data, and it is consistently above that. Thus, the plan is to test $X$ against a sample from that model, as opposed to testing it against shuffled data. This marginal approach works fine. However, I noticed that $X$ and $Y$ are strongly related, and thus decided to try to implement a more advanced procedure, where both variables would be taken into account during testing.

Comment: I’m interested in how this problem came up. // If you have a requirement to run this in ~$40$ hours, won’t it matter what your computing resources? It could make a difference if you’re doing this on your phone versus a gigantic GPU cluster.

Comment: @Dave I just said it to emphasize that I am not theoretically limited by number of samples collected, as opposed to experimental scenarios where only a fixed finite sample is available. I do expect that an optimal solution to this problem would not exceed a few seconds, but I mentioned that computational time is not a problem just in case. I intend to run the code on a desktop PC